# Name error: name 'psycopg2' is not defined

Tags: python, psycopg2, nameerror

Need help with the error below. I'm not sure why the error is happening wherein the relevant libraries are installed.

[image: Name error: name 'psycopg2' is not defined]

Comment: Are you sure the jupyter kernel is configured to use the anaconda interpreter?

Comment: Also, the module isn't the problem. You never imported it, so the **variable** pycopg2 is not defined, as the error says

Comment: Try to use `import psycopg2` before trying to do the connection. I'm not sure, but I think python will not include all your libraries unless you're telling it what to import.

Comment: How to check if jupyter kernel is configured to use the anaconda interpreter? Not sure if the following g info helps, but have been importing libraries just before the excerices i.e. numpy, pandas, etc. without any issues

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I left that comment and then did some research.
Python does not include any library unless you tell it to do.

Use `import psycopg2` before doing the connection and it will recognize the library.

Comment: To clarify, I imported the psycopg2 first. Then I tried the connection. From the screenshot, it shows that psycopg2 is already imported, then I tried the connection.

Comment: No, in the screenshot you can see that the library was `INSTALLED` not `IMPORTED`

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that.